# Does particular+homogeneous capture all solutions for a linear pde?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Specifically, I'm trying to solve $\Delta f(x) = 1$ inside the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $f(x)=1$ for $\|x\|=1$.

I start by finding radially symmetric solutions. The laplacian in spherical coordinates reduces to $\frac{1}{r^2}\partial_r(r^2\partial_rf)=1$. This has solutions of the form $f(r)=\frac{c_1}{r}+c_2+\frac{r^2}{6}$.

Suppose $\Phi(r,\theta,\phi)$ is the general solution to $\Delta \Phi = 0$ inside the unit ball, with $\Phi(1,\theta,\phi)=0$, found by the usual method of separation of variables.

Is $\Phi(r,\theta, \phi) + \frac{c_1}{r}+c_2+\frac{r^2}{6}$ the complete solution to my initial problem? I know this is *a* solution, simply from linearity, but I'm worried I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are both solutions to your inhomogeneous problem with the boundary condition. Then $\Delta(f-g)=\Delta f - \Delta g=1-1=0$. Also for $x$ on the boundary you have $(f-g)(x)=f(x)-g(x)=1-1=0$. Thus $u=f-g$ solves $\Delta u = 0$ with the boundary condition $u(x)=0$ if $\| x \|=1$. By the maximum principle it follows that $u=0$, so the solution to your problem is actually unique.

This seems wrong at first, because you've written a two-parameter family of "solutions". But actually unless $c_1=0$, your function does not have (distributional) Laplacian of $1$ at zero. So the solution is determined only by $c_2$, which is then uniquely determined by the boundary condition.